# Icon not showing, despite split action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, manifest

My icon keeps hiding in the overflow in spite of my efforts to make it visible. According to [android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) I've done it correctly.

This is my menu's layout file.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tasksketch.MainActivity" >

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_task_select"
        android:title="@string/action_task_select"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_done"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


</menu>
```

And this is the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tasksketch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:name="com.example.tasksketch.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is how my app looks.

[image: In the overflow, I have my menu items, despite there being more than enough room to go around]

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: You may need both `android:showAsAction` and `app:showAsAction`.

Comment: I don't know who you are. If you're looking for a reward, I can tell you I don't have money, but what I do have is a surplus of gratitude. Gratitude I would like to show you. If I could, I would find you and I would kiss you! (Sorry for the taken reference, but I'm so happy! Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing as follows:

1.Replace icon name with application icon name in menu item

(android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_done") --> (android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher")

2.Clean Project & Restart